# Firebase Unity iOS library

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

Unity 5.5.2, Firebase Unity SDK 4.0.3, Cocoapod 1.2.1. I have setup Firebase cloud messaging successfully under my Android build in Unity, but I am unable to make iOS build and getting this error

> "ld: library not found for -lz} clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this issue in the 4.2.0 SDK https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#4.2.0 and https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/commit/7d8df60d6a401340f6de8972b45366b9185ee856 of the Play Services Resolver.

Cheers,
Stewart